# Why my styled resizer is not visible at my Chrome extension

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

I'm writing a Chrome extension that add a div element to some pages with content.js file. I want to make my div resizable. I use `resize: vertical;` for this and it works, there is no problem with that.

I also want to style my resizer. I want to use an image for that.

For some reason about nature of extensions, I can't use image path. So I use base64.

```
#commentBox::-webkit-resizer {
 background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIAEAYAAACk6Ai5AAAAIGNIUk0AAHomAACAhAAA...');
}
```

But resizer is not visible when I do it like this.

When I put my cursor on it my cursor changes and I can resize the div. When I inspect the page I can see the image which I put to CSS but it is not visible!

[image: it changes the cursor]

[image: inspect]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: "For some reason about nature of extensions, I can't use image path." - What reasons?

Comment: You need to give the relative path of the image. That means you have to put your extension id to the path. It is not a solid way.

Comment: Would [Predefined messages](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/#overview-predefined) be a solid way?

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work. Still not visible.